# How to parse data from a confluence page using jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, rest, confluence

I want to parse data from a confluence page using a jenkins pipeline, how can this be achieved. Can we use Confluence API with Jenkins for parsing data out of a confluence page.

Comment: Why not just write a script in whatever language you want and get Jenkins to run that?  But otherwise yes you can call APIs with `sh` steps and parse json etc in native Groovy in the pipeline.  Docs are pretty good for this have a go and ask for specific help if you are stuck

Comment: @apr_1985 There are some charts in my confluence page, my object is to show the charts when someone types a keyword. I saw confluence API page, I am confused about how to use those APIs in the code. Just like shown here: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/advanced-searching-using-cql/#field

lines are separated by slash '\' which bash does not reads.